# Perl sort hash, how to sort by $hash{$key}->{secondkey}

Tags: perl

I have a Perl function:

```
my %d;

$d{"aaaa"}->{t1} = "9:49";
$d{"bbbb"}->{t1} = "9:30";

foreach my $k (sort { ($d{$a}->{t1}) <=> ($d{$b}->{t1}) } keys %d)
{
    print "$k:  $d{$k}->{t1}\n";
}
```

I want to sort by t1, so 9:30 before 9:49 and I want to get the result:

```
bbbb:  9:30
aaaa:  9:49
```

but the result is not suitable.

It seems like the result is random?

```
C:\tmp>a.pl
bbbb:  9:30
aaaa:  9:49

C:\tmp>a.pl
bbbb:  9:30
aaaa:  9:49

C:\tmp>a.pl
bbbb:  9:30
aaaa:  9:49

C:\tmp>a.pl
aaaa:  9:49
bbbb:  9:30

C:\tmp>a.pl
bbbb:  9:30
aaaa:  9:49

C:\tmp>a.pl
bbbb:  9:30
aaaa:  9:49

C:\tmp>a.pl
bbbb:  9:30
aaaa:  9:49

C:\tmp>a.pl
aaaa:  9:49
bbbb:  9:30
```

[image]

Comment: Enabling warnings would give you a hint to the problem

Comment: can't reproduce the problem on mac with 5.18.2 . Did a loop of 10000 repeats and the ordering is consistent

Comment: I add a loop in the program, but get 10000 same result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `cmp` instead of `<=>` since you are comparing strings.
The comments are correct and we need to take into consideration 10+ hours.
You need to use sprintf to add leading zero when hours are less than 10 to have strings sorted correctly.

```
foreach my $k (sort { sprintf("%05s", ($d{$a}->{t1})) cmp sprintf("%05s", ($d{$b}->{t1})) } keys %d) {
```

Comment: Comparing by strings (naively, anyway) would put `10:00` before `9:00`, though. You need something that handles such time strings specifically.

Comment: If you want to sort by "clock times", you could do `sort { my ($h_a, $m_a) = split /:/, $d{$a}{t1}; my ($h_b, $m_b) = split /:/, $d{$b}{t1}; $h_a <=> $h_b || $m_a <=> $m_b } keys %d`. This would still of course not understand things like AM and PM and day changes.

Comment: Or if these are (for example) minute:second durations, you could use [List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) like so: `use List::UtilsBy 'nsort_by'; foreach my $k (nsort_by { my ($m, $s) = split /:/, $d{$_}{t1}; $m*60 + $s } keys %d) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

`<=>` is for comparing numbers, but your times have a colon, which makes them strings instead of numbers. One workaround is to just remove the colon, so that `<=>` can operate on them in number context.

```
use v5.10;

say "$_: $d{$_}->{t1}" for sort { $d{$a}->{t1} =~ s/://r <=> $d{$b}->{t1} =~ s/://r } keys %d;
```

The `r` modifier on the substitution means return the new value without altering the old value.

Comment: @user2434977 kindly mark the question as answered, thanks